# Client Server Application for daily report system

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, client-server

I want to make one application in C# or VB.net which allow users(Clients) to fill there daily reports using there user account and allow admin (Server) to manage theme (i.e. Add, View, Edit Reports).

I want to make that kind of application.

Comment: Your question is vague....Please try something and if there is problem ,come here to ask......

Comment: I mean to say that, how can i make simple client server application, which allow clients to fill form and allow admin to see that form.
This application must be worked on LAN only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vague questions get vague answers. A very basic (and slightly *tongue-in-cheek*) strategy:

1. Create a web-page for presenting an interface where the users can enter or upload their reports (maybe have a look at Asp.Net MVC?)
2. Create a simple back-end system  (maybe a service of some kind, using for instance WCF?) to accept and store incoming reports, and retrieve and return existing reports. This should include a database of some kind for storing the reports.
3. Connect your web-page to the back-end system, and use the former as an interface to the latter.

Create one or several AD groups to provide authentication throughout these systems and grant users the appropriate levels of access.

Once you have got started on this and have tried something, you can ask more precise questions here, to which it will be easier to give more constructive answers.